# Как перевести из локальной позиции в глобальную WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, location

Параметр Location у контрола определяет его положение относительно того контейнера, в котором он находится.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли перевести эту *Локейшн* в глобальную, ну или по-другому, относительно самой формы?

Comment: Метод [Control.PointToScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) и обратный ему `Control.PointToClient`